# How to show formatted R output with results='asis' in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way of showing formatter R output in rmarkdown/knitr when using results = 'asis'?

An example would be the following function:

```
myfun <- function() {
  cat("hello!\n")
  cat(c("one" = 1, "two" = 2))
}
```

Then, this chunk will print the second `cat` on a new row:

````
```{r}
myfun()
```
````

[image: nice printing]

But this will ignore the formatting from `myfun`:

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
myfun()
```
````

[image: non-formatted printing]

Is there a way of keeping `results='asis'` but at the same time keep the output of `myfun` formatted as intended?

Comment: So are you just trying to remove the "##" from the output?

Comment: No, I want the newline from the function to be shown in the html output

Comment: By "shown" you mean you literally want to see "\n" rather than get a new line?

Comment: Sorry, I mean: I want to obtain "hello!" and "1 2" on different rows. In a similar way as would appear in the R console

Comment: Which is what the results without "asis" does, but you just don't want it to also draw the "##"? Are you rendering to html? pdf?

Comment: The default output shows the result on two different rows. With 'asis', the result is shown on the same row. I want to keep results='asis', but have the output shown on two different rows, as is the case with the default chunk options. I am rendering to html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the knitr chunk option `results = "asis"` if you are happy to add two or more spaces at the end of the line. That is, instead of `"hello\n"`, you need to write `"hello  \n"` to trigger the line break.

Example R Markdown code:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
myfun <- function() {
  cat("hello!  \n")
  cat(c("one" = 1, "two" = 2))
}
```

```{r results = "asis"}
myfun()
```
````

Gives

[image: output on two lines]

Why the blank spaces? It's because two spaces at the end of a line are used to indicate a hard line break in markdown. For example, this quote is taken from [Pandoc's Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown) (which is the default markdown flavour R Markdown uses):

> Paragraphs
>   A paragraph is one or more lines of text followed by one or more blank lines. Newlines are treated as spaces, so you can reflow your paragraphs as you like. If you need a hard line break, put two or more spaces at the end of a line.

Comment: Worth to mention that default is `results="markup"`.